# Makefile with multiple submodules

Tags: c, makefile

I have following program structure:

```
main.c
Makefile
Submodule
--{somefiles}
--Makefile
```

Submodule is creating library `submodule.a`. It has many source files and it need some libraries.

All I want to know that

1. `Makefile` in submodule knows how to make `submodule.a`
2. `Makefile` in submodule sets variable `SUBMODULE_LDFLAGS` and `SUBMODULE_LDLIBS`

How can I write `Makefile` in root project directory that:

1. it would create `submodule.a` using Makefile in submodule
2. it would add `SUBMODULE_LDFLAGS` and `SUBMODULE_LDLIBS` to its own variable?

AT the end I want the following command in main `Makefile` works correctly:

```
TARGET = MyProgram
OBJS = $(TARGET).o submodule/submodule.a

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

Now it creates `MyProgram.o` and cannot create `MyProgram`, because `Makefile` doesn't know how to make `submodule/submodule.a`.

I can add lines:

```
submodule/submodule.a:
    make -C submodule
```

but it won't help me with missing libraries.

Comment: Can you modify `submodule/Makefile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way for the sub-Make to pass variables to the parent process. There are (at least) two indirect ways.

You could have the sub-Make write a file containing the variable values, which the parent Make could then read.

You could copy the part of `submodule/Makefile` that constructs those variables, and put it into `Makefile`. Better still, you could isolate that code in a separate file that both makefiles would then `include`.

**EDIT:**

One disadvantage of recursive Make is that it interrupts much of Make's dependency handling. In this case, there's no clean way to have the sub-make run when and only when one of the library's sources is changed.

You can put the list of submodule sources -- or the code that constructs the list -- in a separate file which both makefiles will `include`. Then those files can be among the prerequisites of `$(TARGET)`.

*Or,* you could make `submodule/submodule.a` a PHONY target. In that case, Make will rebuild the binary every time, but otherwise it'll work perfectly.

Comment: What about instruction to make `submodule.a`? My solution won't regenerate `submodule.a` after any changes were made to `submodule.a` sources.

Comment: @Ari: That wasn't in your question, but it's easy to address. Are you satisfied with my answer about the variables?

Comment: partially, but it seems, that there is no better solution and that solution works.